# Reading excel/csv files from desktop to Jupyter in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter

Is it possible to read excel or csv files from your computer desktop to a jupyter notebook in google cloud? how?

Comment: No, code running in the Google Cloud cannot access the files on your desktop computer.

Comment: You need to move your files at least to a GCP bucket.

Comment: @RomanGherta how can i do it after moving my files to the gcp bucket?

Comment: Hi @EkoWidianto I provided below a more detailed answer yesterday. You call the bucket file with gs://mybucketname/file.csv

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Google Cloud Shell and create a Datalab instance

   > datalab create datalab-instance-name
2. Connect to your new datalab instance

   > datalab connect datalab-instance-name
3. After GCloud Shell connects to your datalab instance, click on Web Preview (right corner of the console) and choose port 8081. A new window will open with a Jupyter Notebook Environment.
4. Create a new GS bucket and upload your file. You will be able to access the file later via the following URI notation

   *`gs://mybucketname/file.csv`*
5. From your Datalab instance write the following to access the CSV file

   > ```
   > import pandas as pd
   > from io import BytesIO
   > %gcs read --object "gs://mybucketname/file.csv" --variable csv_as_bytes
   > df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(csv_as_bytes))
   > df.head()
   > ```
6. When finished, delete the datalab instance to avoid extra cost

   > datalab delete --delete-disk datalab-instance-name

Good luck!